# Disable google analytics tracking during live run

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

According to the terms for Google analytics you need to provide the user with a option to opt out of the tracking. But I feel, documentation is not very clear on how to do that. This what I got so far.

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.tracker);
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(false);
t.enableAutoActivityTracking(false);
t.enableExceptionReporting(false);
```

Will this disable all tracking including events like this.

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("category")
    .setAction("test")
    .setLabel("label")
.build());
```

If not how do I completely disable tracking during run on user device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setAppOptOut(true);`.

In Google Analytics documentation([1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#opt-out)), there is simple example with shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

userPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener () {

  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(TRACKING_PREF_KEY)) {
      GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setAppOptOut(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));
    } else {
      // Any additional changed preference handling.
    }
  }
});
```

Note: This is different from disabling Google Analytics during testing / development. If your aim is to disable during test/development, use ([2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#testing))

```
GoogeAnalytics.getInstance(this).setDryRun(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `SharedPreference` setting and if the user opt-out Analytics tracking you don't send the Analytics update.